# Problems with Div tag when using include JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

### template.jsp

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="top"></div>
   <div id="banner"></div>
   <div id="menu"></div>
   <div id="content">
        <div id="content-left"></div>
        <div id="content-right"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

### index.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/template.jsp"%>
```

I have two jsp pages as above and . Now i want to put some texts and forms into index.jsp and they must go between div tags with id is "content-left". How can i do?

I tried to do as below but it's not working!

### index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content-left">
<!--text and form here -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try <div id="content-left">
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/templates/template.jsp"%>
</div>

Comment: I've already tried following your guide but it's still not work bro!